# qt customized widget

Tags: qt, qt5

i have a customized widget. this customized widget which loads two images via animation is supposed to take two small corners of the mainwindow. The problem I face is when I execute the program it clears everything inside mainwindow and only shows the customized widget which is an image. this is because I overwrote the paintEvent function inside the customized widget. so, now, how can I tell mainwindow to keep its own paintEvent as well as executing the customized widget paintEvent?

well, i solved this by setting a widget as the customized object base.

Comment: And you're sure that the custom widget is not just too large? Because this sounds to me, like the custom widget simply takes up all the available space.

Answer (score 0):

The paintEvent function is virtual and is being overridden by your function (assuming your customized widget is deriving from QWidget). If you want to call the base class, you may want to call QWidget::paintEvent() inside your paintEvent().

Comment: While that is true, I think he has a different problem...I mean, it's not like he overrid the mainwindow, did he?

Comment: I don't understand why I shoud add QWidget::paintEvent() inside paintEvent()